# An interesting Casimir configuration

Tags: vacuum, casimir-effect

A problem related to an interesting  Casimir configuration.

I have the following configuration , related to a modified Casimir experiment.  We have two parallel metal plates and an  orthogonal  metal plate connecting the two parallel plates. Note that this is very close to the experimental setup of the original Casimir experiment,  except for the orthogonal plate (connecting the two parallel plates at one end).   I would like to know all the Casimir  forces that exist in this configuration.

For clarification you can see the following [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yINm.jpg)

My naive intuition could be incorrect, but my impression is that the asymmetric radiation  pressure due to quantum fluctuations would lead to the emergence of a certain force (parallel to the parallel plates), but I don't know if the QFT / QED calculations justify my intuition (where in fact  these virtual particles are just an intuitive representation of links in Feynman diagrams, linked to terms in infinite perturbation series).

[Heuristic derivation of the Casimir effect from Heisenberg  Uncertainty Principle](https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S0217732318501407)

[Heuristic derivation of the Casimir effect from  the Generalized  Uncertainty Principle](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.02414)

Closely following the arguments in these two papers, that force mentioned above does indeed exist (for the three plate system mentioned above).

I hope somebody here can quickly settle this problem, so I don't spend a long time digging for an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/504630/2451

Comment: Hi Cristian Dumitrescu. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Comment: Otherwise the new version looks fine and ready to be reopened.

Comment: @Qmechanic  Sorry, misunderstood what you meant .

Comment: No problem. I reopened your post.

Comment: Thank you, I'm not very good with the rules.